# "First item from both sets" vs "First items from both sets"

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I was commenting on a question on Stackoverflow and found myself writing:

> You are comparing the first item from both sets

Meaning in this case that the OP was taking an item from one collection, and an item from a second collection, and comparing them, *with emphasis on the fact that the comparison was of the **very first item*** picked from each collection.

My phrasing made sense in my head because in each set, you take the first **item**.  But on further thought, it seemed odd because you wouldn't say

> You are comparing the item.

Yet when I look at the phrase

> You are comparing the first **items** from both sets

it seems unnatural to me.

Is my original phrase correct, or should I have written "items?"

I've done some googling and couldn't find a clear example that differentiates between the two forms.

Comment: What you might want is "You are comparing the first item from _each_ set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the phrases are similar. However, when you say:

> the first item from both sets

You refer to the *very* first item in each set. But, when you say:

> the first item*s* from both sets

it *can* refer to the multiple items at the beginning of each set.

As commented by @Xanne:

A sentence you can consider using is

> You are comparing the first item from *each* set.